# Unable to connect to SMTP using PHP

Tags: php, smtp, phpmailer, email

I am trying to send an email with another host and every time I got this `error-> Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed`. Here is my code

```
    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 0;
    $mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

    $mail->Host = ' host IP '; 
    $mail->Port = 587;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl'; // I had also tried with TLS

    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->Username = "my@username.com";
    $mail->Password = "password";

    $mail->setFrom('my@username.com', 'MY Personal');

    $mail->addAddress($To);

    if($MoreAddresses != "")
    {
        foreach($MoreAddresses as $Address)
        {
            $mail->addAddress($Address);
        }
    }

    $mail->Subject = $Subject;
    $mail->msgHTML($Body);
    $mail->AltBody = 'This email contains HTML contents.';
    if($MoreAddresses != "")
    {
        foreach($MoreAddresses as $Address)
        {
            $mail->addAddress($Address);
        }
    }

    $mail->Subject = $Subject;
    $mail->msgHTML($Body);
    $mail->AltBody = 'This email contains HTML contents.';

    if (!$mail->send()) 
    {
        return "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    }
    else
    {
        return "Message sent!";
    }
```

I had tried with many of question but couldn't help me well.

Comment: There must be more error mesasges in your logs. Look into.

Comment: You might start by asking yourself why you do the `MoreAddresses` processing twice.

Comment: Then ask yourself if it seems logical to test an array using `if($MoreAddresses != "")`

Comment: Then ask yourself is `$MoreAddresses` actually an array

Comment: Then ask yourself is the `php_openssl` extension enabled in PHP

Comment: Use `$mail->SMTPDebug = 1;` to get error and message.

Comment: @ThinkTank Add `$mail->SMTPDebug  = 2;` to enables SMTP debug information

Comment: Then you could ask yourself why you didnt look at the freely available [phpMailer Examples available on their website](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/index.php?pg=exampleasmtp)

Comment: i had used "$mail->ErrorInfo" to get error logs. so can you tell me that how to get other errors also.

Comment: RiggsFolly, that's a long-obsolete source for examples; current ones are [here](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/tree/master/examples). The OP will actually already have copies of these as they are included in the source bundle.

Comment: Your first port of call should be to [read the docs](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting), not posting the same question that's been asked hundreds of times on SO.

Comment: @RiggsFolly The documentation specify `1 = errors and messages` and `2 = messages only`. But both are ok I think.

Answer (score 1):

```
$mail->IsSMTP();
$mail->Host = "smtp.gmail.com";
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->SMTPSecure = "ssl";
$mail->Username = "myemail@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "**********";
$mail->Port = "465";
```

That is a working configuration.
try to replace what you have

Comment: No add that to your original answer. One answer per questions is all that is required

Comment: i had checked over secure host network and it is showing for  "000.000.000.000:465 (urd) is open." does it creates any problem in that host.

Comment: You try simple php mail function and check it work or not.

Answer (score 1):

This code for php mail

```
$to = "".$_REQUEST['txtphp_to']."";
$subject = "Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula.";
$txt = "Duis mollis, est non commodo luctus, nisi erat porttitor ligula, eget lacinia odio sem nec elit. Cras mattis consectetur purus sit amet fermentum.
Nullam quis risus eget urna mollis ornare vel eu leo. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Nullam id dolor id nibh ultricies vehicula.";
$headers = "From: $s_emailid" . "\r\n";// .
if(mail($to,$subject,$txt,$headers))
{
echo "done";
}
else
{
echo "error";
}
```

Comment: Three answer to the same question is a little excessive. One answer should be enough for anyone. _Once a King always a King, but Once a knights enough_

Answer (score 0):

When you use

```
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
```

then the ports are: tls=587 , ssl=465.

Comment: Add that to your answer, _using the edit link_ not as a comment. Nobody can read code in comments

Comment: set the SMTP port for the outMail server        
use either 25 or 587

Answer (score 0):

Add the mail.php use the below code it's working fine for me...

```
include "../Mail/Mail.php";

$from = "test<emai>"; 
$to = $toname."<".$tomail.">"; 
$subject = $subject;
$body =$body; 
$host ="ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
$port = "465"; 
$username = "test@gmail.com"; 
$password = "123456"; 
$headers['From'] =$from;
$headers['To'] = $to;
$headers['Bcc'] = $from;
$headers['Subject'] = $subject;
$headers['Reply-To'] = 'no-replay<no-replay>';
$smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',   
array ('host' => $host,     'port' => $port,   
'auth' => true,     'username' => $username,     'password' => $password)); 
$mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body); 
if (PEAR::isError($mail)) 
{  
  $mail->getMessage() ; 
}
```